# how to select Columns using SQL which has data length greater than given length

Tags: sql, multiple-columns, content-length

I have a table with specific columns and rows. I would like to select columns which has data more than length 7.

For ex:
Table has columns

```
Name      Address   PhoneNumber
AAA       AAAAAAAA   12345678
BBBBB     BBBBBBB    47854
CCC       FFFF       76643
```

Here columns 'Address   ' and 'Phone Number' has data length more than 7. So it should display,

Address
PhoneNumber

as results.  This is for a particular table. Here I do not know already that Address and PhoneNumber are the columns which have data greater than length 7. Only from the query result I will be able to find it.

`SELECT <<all_columns>> from table where length(columns)>7` is my input requirement.

The LENGTH or LEN functions in 'Where' clause gives option to give only one specific column name

instead of `LENGTH(COL_NAME)` , I need option as where LENGTH(<> or something like `LENGTH(*)) > 7` should be given as input.

How that can be achieved?

Comment: I have updated my question with my need to execute a query against a table to find out which columns have data more than length 7. I hope I explained correctly for the requirement for which I need help.

Answer (score 12):

So HAVING is probably the clause youd want to use. Obviously, you can expand to include all columns and increase the having. see this:

```
 SELECT 
      Name,
      Address, 
      Phonenumber, 
      LEN(Address) AS AddyLength
 FROM
      yourTables
 GROUP BY
      Name,
      Address, 
      Phonenumber, 
 HAVING
      LEN(Address)>7
```

Comment: Change `LEN(Address)>=7` to `LEN(Address)>7` right?

Comment: `SELECT explanation FROM doug_coats WHERE Comment IN ('fine', 'sure', 'whatever', 'lol')` :-)

Comment: ; with explanation AS (SELECT humor, jaunt, sass FROM sillyBehavriors WHERE bored=TRUE) SELECT * FROM explanation @KayNelson

Answer (score 2):

If you can live with the results in columns rather than rows:

```
select (case when max(length(name)) > 7 then 'Name;' else '' end) ||
       (case when max(length(address)) > 7 then 'address;' else '' end) ||
       (case when max(length(phone)) > 7 then 'phone;' else '' end) 
from t;
```

Comment: if you write unions instead of `||` (or just submit 3 selects sequentially), then it is in columns &  I think, what @Sujata Rajesh needs.

Comment: Actually this query is required to find which columns have data of length more than 7. Hence I cannot use this query. This query must ran in big table which has more than 25 columns also. It should be dynamic one which can be run in any table.

Comment: lolz, @DougCoats ... yeah, then you need something "procedural" and with "root access" ...and very "vendor specific" `@SujathaRajesh`

Answer (score 0):

As I read you need a dynamic sql for larger tables than your example (that should be part of your question)

I used unpivot to compare all lengths at once

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(100) = 'YourTableName'
DECLARE @MaxLen INT = 7

DECLARE @Definition 
    TABLE (
        ColumnName VARCHAR(50)
    )

INSERT @Definition
SELECT C.Name 
FROM 
sys.columns C
JOIN sys.tables T
ON C.object_id = T.object_id
WHERE t.name = @TableName

DECLARE @Columns VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @ColumnsWithCast VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SET @Columns = STUFF(
                    (SELECT ',' + ColumnName
                     FROM     @Definition
                     FOR XML PATH('')
                    ), 
                    1, 
                    1, 
                    '')

SET @ColumnsWithCast = STUFF(
                    (SELECT ',CAST(' + ColumnName + ' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS ' + ColumnName
                     FROM     @Definition
                     FOR XML PATH('')
                    ), 
                    1, 
                    1, 
                    '')

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Field
FROM (
        SELECT 
            ' + @ColumnsWithCast + '  
        FROM ' + @TableName + ' A 
) p  
UNPIVOT (
    Value FOR Field IN (
        ' + @Columns + '
    )  
)AS unpvt
WHERE LEN(Value) > @MaxLen
'

DECLARE @ParamDefinition NVARCHAR(100) = N'@MaxLen INT'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @ParamDefinition, @MaxLen = @MaxLen
```

It will generate this code with all the existing columns

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Field
FROM (
        SELECT 
            CAST(Name AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Name, 
            CAST(Address AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Address,
            CAST(PhoneNumber AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS PhoneNumber,  
        FROM HIERARCHY A 
) p  
UNPIVOT (
    Value FOR Field IN (
        Name, Address, PhoneNumber
    )  
)AS unpvt
WHERE LEN(Value) > @MaxLen
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I am getting errors when running this query. Not sure if mistake is my side. I will check after resolving the problems and let you know.

Comment: Is it a procedure? What to do to execute this directly copying and pasting in my TOAD tool?

Comment: Is an script, you can run it directly or put it into a stored procedure, as you mentioned that you need it for large tables, it generates dynamic sql code so you can run it for any desired table, anyway I edited the answer to show you the generated code if yo prefer to use it directly